# Hide external URL from knowing its running on electron

Tags: javascript, electron

So I'm trying to use Discord to authenticate users in my Electron app and was thinking of using a popup window to show the authorize with Discord screen. However, it seems like the Discord app recognizes that its running on an Electron instance and tells me that I'm running an old version of the Discord desktop app instead of the expected authorization screen. Is there any way fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987668/cant-use-discord-oauth2-in-electron-application), it seems like I just have to disable nodeIntegration for that specific window.