# Ionic React + Electron Discord authentication

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, electron, discord

I've been trying to implement Discord OAuth in my Electron app, with a redirect to a localhost url. I wanted to avoid opening any new windows so I started by using history. That ended quickly because you can't push a url that is from a different origin.

I then tried:

```
window.open(url);
```

This opens another electron window which I didn't really want. The next thing I tried was:

```
window.require('electron').shell.openExternal(url);
```

To open the users default browser instead. This is fine but I realised it will not work because when it redirects to the localhost url, it doesn't redirect through electron so all you see is a `Not Found` page. It would work if I specified the port 8100 but I don't know if every user's app will run on that specific port. Unfortunately, I can't even dynamically add the port to the redirect url because it would need to be added to the Discord application so it knows it's allowed to redirect to that url.

Because of this, I went back to `window.open` instead. However that also errosr, but not on my side. One of the scrips on Discord's side throws an error which seems to only occur when opening it in an electron window:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentWindow' of undefined
    at r.u.componentDidMount (cccf4effcc0925e4e5bb.js:2)
    at bu (cccf4effcc0925e4e5bb.js:2)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (cccf4effcc0925e4e5bb.js:2
...
```

The only post similar to the error is: [Can't use Discord OAuth2 in Electron application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987668/cant-use-discord-oauth2-in-electron-application) but their fix was to disable node modules which is sadly not an option because I require some modules through `window.require`.

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by using a preload script containing

```
if (window.location.host === "discord.com") {
  window.require = null;
}
```